# Android game: removing moving fingeracross the screen (swiping/flinging?)

Tags: android, swipe

I have an Android game app that populates the screen with tiny images (circles).  The game is to tap the circles on the screen as quickly as possible until they all disappear.  The problem is you can circumvent the game easily by swiping/moving one's finger across the screen (and making every circle touched disappear).  In four swipes you're done with the game. I'm not even sure of the correct terminology.

Any ideas?  onFling? onLongPress?  I do not know.

Comment: onTouch, but discard all the events that have action other than ACTION_DOWN

Comment: @fdreger  Sorry.  Can you explain this?

Comment: Wow!  This works!  Thanks!  Write it up and I'll mark it as the solution or after awhile I will write the solution with my one line of code.

Comment: I made a New Year's resolution not to write any answers on StackOverflow this year (the place is a time vampire!) and instead focus on something more constructive... I can sort of excuse myself for writing a short comment or two, but a full fledged answer would be too heavy on my conscience :-)